# Dynamically assign values to named list using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny, shiny-reactivity

This post is an extension of a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71974188/how-to-retrieve-loop-generated-variables-across-multiple-outputs-in-shiny) for which the answer provided was perfectly suitable. However, I'd like to make the app more flexible by assigning the list item names dynamically, using the values in `unique(iris$Species)` instead of hard coding the items in the named list. I've tried to do this by assigning the items in the named list via a for loop: `for (m in species_list){ paste0("species_",m) = species_table[[m]]}`. However, when I run the app I get a error saying "subscript out of bounds". I've included the complete replicable example below:

````
data(iris)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(selectInput("portfolio", label = "Select Species", choices = unique(iris$Species))),
    fluidRow(tableOutput("result"))
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  species_list <- unique(iris$Species)
  
  species_function <- reactive({
    
    species_table <- list()
    for (i in reactiveValuesToList(species_list)){
      local({
        j <- i
        species_table[[j]] <<- iris[iris$Species==j,]
      })
    }
    
    return(list(
      
      for (m in species_list){
        paste0("species_",m) = species_table[[m]]      
      }
      
    ))
    
  })
  
  output$result <- renderTable({
    input$portfolio
    species_table2 <- list()
    
    for (p in reactiveValuesToList(species_list)){
      local({
        q <- p
        species_table2[[reactive({q})()]] <<- species_function()[[paste0("species_",reactive({q})())]][1:5, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")]
      })
    }
    
    print(species_table2[[input$portfolio]])
    return(species_table2[[input$portfolio]])
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)```
````

Comment: Use `setNames()` to add names to the list. Something like `setNames(species_table, paste0("species_",species_list))` No need for a loop.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, that (together with another fix to specify species_list as a reactiveValue) appears to have resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

The following modified code, incorporating feedback from @MrFlick and specifying species_list as a reactive value, functions as expected.

```
library(shiny)
data(iris)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(selectInput("portfolio", label = "Select Species", choices = unique(iris$Species))),
    fluidRow(tableOutput("result"))
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  species_names <- as.character(unique(iris$Species))
  species_list <- reactiveValues()
  
  for(i in 1:length(species_names)) {
    
    species_list[[paste0("species_", i)]] <- species_names[[i]]
    
  }
  
  species_function <- reactive({
    
    species_table <- list()
    for (i in reactiveValuesToList(species_list)){
      local({
        j <- i
        species_table[[j]] <<- iris[iris$Species==j,]
      })
    }
    
    setNames(species_table, species_names)
    
  })
  
  output$result <- renderTable({
    input$portfolio
    species_table2 <- list()
    
    for (p in reactiveValuesToList(species_list)){
      local({
        q <- p
        species_table2[[reactive({q})()]] <<- species_function()[[reactive({q})()]][1:5, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")]
      })
    }
    
    return(species_table2[[input$portfolio]])
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```